# How to prompt location sharing permission in browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

how do I prompt location share permission to user using JavaScript. For example whenever we visit google maps browser automatically asks for share location. My Aim is to prompt user for permission to share location. As I'm working in tracking module in AngularJS though i need to prompt user for permission in google Chrome.
Thank you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function like this. Calling this function will raise the popup.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  yourFunction(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

When position is available, yourFunction will get executed.

Comment: This will give me location where as i need permission for sharing location.

Comment: Using this code alone will make the browser show the common-seen popup asking for permission to share location.

Comment: I just tried this in Chrome. It immediately called the error function with "User denied the request for Geolocation." Note: answer above does not include the error function. I used: 

 var _positionOptions = {maximumAge:120000, timeout:30000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(okFunc, errorFunc,_curPositionOptions);

Answer (score 1):

Some extra info, you can use this API to check the permission status of geolocation sharing in the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API

This API returns a PermissionStatus object which includes the "state" property, the state of permission to access geolocation

```js
function handlePermission() {
  navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
    if (result.state == 'granted') {
      report(result.state);
    } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
      report(result.state);
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(revealPosition,positionDenied,geoSettings);
    } else if (result.state == 'denied') {
      report(result.state);
    }
    result.onchange = function() {
      report(result.state);
    }
  });
}

function report(state) {
  console.log('Permission ' + state);
}

handlePermission();
```